# pdfswitch API PDF generating, margin problem

Tags: php, json, pdf

I'm using pdfswitch.io to generate dynamic PDF through curl/PHP.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://pdfswitch.io/api/convert/",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>
    array(
        "Authorization: Bearer xxxxx",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ),
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
    "source" => $SOURCE,
    "page_orientation" => "portrait",
    "page_format" => "A5",
    "custom_footer" => '',
    "margins" => "{'top': '50px', 'bottom': '50px'}",
))
));
```

Unfortunately it gives me an error if I use the margin option. Any idea what I've done wrong?